# Cannot install R package coin

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I've been trying to install the R package coin for a project and I keep getting these odd errors.

[Error message when I use the install.packages("coin") call.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7U62.png)

I was able to install the package from the coin_1.4-3.tar.gz file downloaded from CRAN (I have a Windows PC), but now I get another error message when I try to load coin using the library(coin) call.

[Error message when I use the library(coin) call.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xohFE.png)

Would really appreciate any help you can provide.

As an aside, here is the message I received when I was able to install coin from the coin_1.4-3.tar.gz file:

[Page one of code responding to attempts to install coin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fk9g.png)
[Page two of code responding to attempts to install coin and error message upon calling library(coin).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C7bL.png)

I expected the package to be installed when I called install.packages("coin"). When that didn't work, I used the RStudio Install Packages option in the dropdown under Tools and tried to install the coin_1.4-3.tar.gz file I downloaded from CRAN.

Comment: Already tried `install.packages('sandwich')`?

Comment: Did you go look to see whether `coin` is actually stored under  `cran/...../rstudio/...` ?  I see the binary in https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/coin_1.4-3.zip

Comment: You are on Windows, so life will be a lot easier if you install the binary instead of the source tarball.  The message that some file didn't exist on cran.rstudio.com is likely transient; if you try `install.packages("coin")` again, you'll probably get better results.  If not, you could try using a different CRAN mirror (though in my experience, the one you used is one of the most reliable).

Comment: BTW, posting images of error messages makes things harder for everyone.  You should cut and paste the text of the message into your question, probably marked as code so the formatting doesn't get changed.